# Как создать такое методами JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно создать такой блок методами JS

```
<style>
.style {
text-align: center;
}
</style>
<div class="center" id="block">
Text</br>
<img src="images/img.png">
</div>
```

Вт как я делаю:

```
  var elem  = document.createElement('div');
  block.classList.add('style');
  block.textContent = "Text";
  body.append(elem);
```

Как присвоить id создаваемому блоку и вставить в него изображение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте свойства [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/id) и [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) созданного элемента

```js
const elem = document.createElement("div");
elem.id = "block"
elem.classList.add("style");
elem.innerHTML = `Text</br>
    <img src="images/img.png">`;
document.body.append(elem);
```